# Ruby on Rails, find top 5 Users ordered by purchases

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, User and Purchase.
A `User has_many :purchases` and a `Purchase belongs_to :user`

Purchases fields are:

```
id, product_id, user_id, amount, created_at
```

What I am trying to achieve is a method call such as:
`User.top_five` which would return the 5 Users with the highest purchase value, i.e. the sum of the purchases.amount field for each user.

I also want to be able to do something like `User.top_five(:start_date=>'01/01/2010',:end_date=>'31/12/2010')` , i.e. select a time period to calculate the top five users.

So I've been trying to get the right combination of joins, sums, order_bys etc, but I'm just not getting it. So hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!
Hopefully I've given enough info here, this is my first question.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest something like

```
def self.top_five(start_date, end_date)
  User.all(:select => "users.*, SUM(purchased.amount) as purchased_sum",
           :joins => "LEFT JOIN purchases AS purchased ON purchased.user_id = users.id",
           :group => "users.id",
           :conditions => ["purchased.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date, end_date],
           :order => "purchased_sum DESC",
           :limit => 5)
end
```

Comment: thanks marcel. I had to tweak the sql a bit , but that definitely helped me.