# Is my simple vote system implemenation in Rails efficient?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I designed a simple voting system in my sample Rails app.

I have a controller that calls the method from the Vote Model

`@popular_links = Link.includes(:votes).top`

And this is how my `top` method in my `link.rb` works:

```
def self.top
    self.all.sort do |a, b|

    # Calculate each link's vote counts
    a_votes = a.votes.where(:up => true).count -
              a.votes.where(:up => false).count
    b_votes = b.votes.where(:up => true).count -
              b.votes.where(:up => false).count

    # Compare it from highest value to lowest value
    b_votes <=> a_votes
  end.first(6)
end
```

I'm not sure what I did is efficient.

Or is there a one line Rails SQL command that could do that for me
to sort the calculations like this?

Comment: Voting systems use Redis to store keys. (Also stackoverflow). There's many good articles about it.

Comment: This would be better on the [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: Thank you guys! I'll look up on Redis for proper solutions.

Comment: Redis is just another data store - it's doesn't constitute to efficiency of code - I'll write some basic pointers

Comment: Did you have a look at the https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up gem? This takes care of the entire "vote household" for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rename attribute `:up` to `:vote` (my preference)
2. Use SQL to calculate at DB-level
3. Only return 6 records from db (you're returning all data currently)

**Code**

```
@popular_links = Link.includes(:votes).top

def self.top
    self.all.sort do |a, b|
        a_votes = a.votes.sum(:up)
        b_votes = b.votes.sum(:up)
        b_votes <=> a_votes
    end.first(6)
end

- or - 

def self.top
    self.joins(:votes).select("links.*, SUM(votes.up) as votes_num").order("votes_num DESC").limit(6)
end
```

I found the second one here: [Ruby on Rails, find top 5 Users ordered by purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606216/ruby-on-rails-find-top-5-users-ordered-by-purchases)

At db level, your `boolean` columns are just `tinyint` in MYSQL (check [data types here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL#The_Environment)), which means `true` / `false` is either going to be `1` or `0`. Therefore a sum of the column will give the net votes for the link

Comment: I originally designed to show negative votes on purpose, but your answer did provide resources to help me think through my code. Thanks!